# How to update a slot in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component simplified below.

Here is the template

```
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

The slot may contain HTML, which is why I decided to use a slot rather than a prop which I would simply bind to. I'd like to keep it that way.

I have a method that gets new HTML from the server. I'd like to use this new HTML to update the slot. I'm not sure if slots are reactive and how I can accomplish this.

I can view the default slot using `this.$slots.default[0]`, but I don't know how to update it with a string of HTML content. Simply assigning the string to the element is obviously incorrect, to `.innerHtml` does not work because it isn't an available function, and to `.text` doesn't work. I assume that even though the text element exists on the slot object, the element properties take precedence.

Per suggestion in comments, I've tried this along with a computer property.

```
<span v-html="messageContent"><slot></slot></span>
```

But now the problem is that it overwrites the slot passed to me.

**How can I reactively update a slot with new HTML in Vue.JS?**

Comment: If you're using a slot, it means you are passing in HTML when using the component's tag in the consuming parent's template. Simply pass the HTML to the parent component, and have it injected into the component.

Comment: @Terry "Simply pass the HTML to the parent component, and have it injected into the component". Sorry, I'm new to Vue. I know how to do this when creating a component, but I'm not sure how to pass or inject to an existing components slot. Also, to be clear, there's only one component, no parent or children.

Comment: try to return the html from the server with a computed property, and use a wrapper with v-html

Comment: @afcosta I tried but it did not work, see edit in question for exactly how I tried to apply it.

Comment: you need to do it outside, in the parent component, in the parent return the html with computed, then use a div that has the slot name and the v-html

Comment: inside you just recieve the html

Comment: if you just want to put your HTML to the default slot, try `<component><template v-html="yourHtml"></template></component>`

Comment: @afcosta that works. Now the problem is that it overwrites the content passed through the slot. How can I get the HTML string of the passed slot?

Comment: @Sphinx then I'd just be using a property to pass HTML to the component, in which case I'd just pass it as a bind on the `<component>` element like I already do with some other elements. I prefer not to have to put HTML inside a ="" type syntax.

Comment: so you don't want to overwrite, just add the html to the current slot?

Comment: @afcosta I want to overwrite after an event happens. Initially, I need to use the content passed through the slot.

Comment: the computed react to changes in a property for example, i don't know which event you want to have, but imagine, a click event, if you click and change the computed property it will react to those changes

Comment: @afcosta I'm sorry, I'm a little lost as to the details of how to implement that.

Comment: create a pen with the current state of what you have, i change it

Comment: it seems you'd like to update the content of the default slot in current component not parent component? right?

Comment: @afcosta the whole state is private and also quite long, the info for a MVC example should all be in the question I think.

Comment: @Sphinx Exactly correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your issue comes from a misunderstanding of how `<slot>` inherently works in VueJS. Slots are used to interweave content from a consuming parent component into a child component. See it as a HTML equivalent of `v-bind:prop`. When you use `v-bind:prop` on a component, you are effectively passing data into a child component. This is the same as slots.

Without any concrete example or code from your end, this answer is *at best* just guess-work. I assume that your parent component is a VueJS app itself, and the child component is the one that holds the `<slot>` element.

```
<!-- Parent template -->
<div id="app">
    <custom-component>
        <!-- content here -->   
    </custom-component>
</div>

<!-- Custom component template -->
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

In this case, the app has a default ground state where it passes static HTML to the child component:

```
<!-- Parent template -->
<div id="app">
    <custom-component>
        <!-- Markup to be interweaved into custom component -->
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </custom-component>
</div>

<!-- Custom component template -->
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

Then, when an event is fired, you want to replace that ground-state markup with new incoming markup. This can be done by storing the incoming HTML in the `data` attribute, and simply using `v-html` to conditionally render it. Let's say we want to store the incoming markup in app's `vm.$data.customHTML`:

```
data: {
    customHTML: null
}
```

Then your template will look like this:

```
<!-- Parent template -->
<div id="app">
    <custom-component>
        <div v-if="customHTML" v-html="customHTML"></div>
        <div v-else>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </custom-component>
</div>

<!-- Custom component template -->
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

Note that in contrast to the code you have tried, the differences are that:

- It is the **parent component** (i.e. the *consuming component*) that is responsible for dictating what kind of markup to pass to the child
- The child component is as *dumb* as it gets: it simply receives markup and renders it in the `<slot>` element

---

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var customComponent = Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: '#custom-component-template'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    customHTML: null
  },
  components: {
    customComponent: customComponent
  },
  methods: {
    updateSlot: function() {
      this.customHTML = '<p>Foo bar baz</p>';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-component {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>I am the app</h1>
  <button type="button" @click="updateSlot">Click me to update slot content</button>
  <custom-component>
    <div v-if="customHTML" v-html="customHTML">
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </custom-component>
</div>

<!-- custom-component template -->
<script type="text/template" id="custom-component-template">
  <div class="custom-component">
    <h2>I am a custom component</h2>
    <!-- slot receives markup set in <custom-component> -->
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Below is my solution though I don't like this opinion (load html into slot directly in current component level) because it breaks the rules for the slot. And I think you should do like this way (`<component><template v-html="yourHtml"></template></component>`), it will be better because Slot will focus on its job as Vue designed.

The key is `this.$slots.default` must be one VNode, so I used `extend()` and `$mount()` to get the _vnode.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div><slot></slot><a style="color:green">Child</a></div>',
  mounted: function(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let slotBuilder = Vue.extend({
        // use your html instead
        template: '<div><a style="color:red">slot in child</a></div>',
      })
      let slotInstance = new slotBuilder()
      this.$slots.default = slotInstance.$mount()._vnode
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }, 2000)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      test: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<child><h1>Test</h1></child>
</div>
```