# Append child to $slot.default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that I need display some custom modal on screen. I don't know where I should put this dialog content, so I did something like that:

```
<template>
    <div class="ComponentItself">
        <div v-show="false" ref="ModalContent">
            Hello!
        </div>

        <button v-on:click="showModal">Show modal</button>
    </div>
</template>

[...]
```

> **Note:** I could not set the tag name of `[ref=ModalContent]` to `template` because the vue reserves this tag to another feature.

My idea is when I click on "show modal" it open creates an instance of another component (`v-dialog`) that I have created with the `[ref=ModalContent]` content (it should be compiled to support nested vue components).

```
import Dialog from './Dialog';

const DialogCtor = Vue.extend(Dialog);
const dialog = new DialogCtor({ propsData: {...} });

dialog['$slots'].default = [ this.$refs['templateNewFolder'].innerHTML ];

{something like document.body.appendChild(dialog.$el)}
```

This another component have a slot that could receives the HTML content to be displayed inside of that. And it just not works. The modal is displayed, but the slot content is `undefined` or the HTML content not parsed.

```
<div class="Dialog">
    [...]
    <slot></slot>       
    [...]
</div>
```

The current result is something like:

[image]
[image]

---

**What I need:**

- I need to know if I am on the right way. I have about the `component` feature, but I could not identify or understand if it is/could resolve my problem;
- What I could do to make it work;
- Some similar project could help it, but I could not found anyone;
- Maybe I could resolve my problem if is possible I just `.appendChild()` directly to `$slot.default`, but it is not possible;

Comment: `$slots.default` should be one VNode, not one `['htmlContent']`, check [Update slot.default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50243546/5665870), but it is not one regular way. Probably uses the directive=`v-html` will be better.

Comment: or uses `v-bind:is="component_name"` is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me this might be a case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

What probably happens is that you do not need to *manually* fill `$slot.default`, but use your `Dialog` component a more standard way. Since there is little detail about the latter in your question, that component might also need some refactoring to fit this "standard way".

So a more standard approach would be to directly use your `<custom-dialog>` component in the template of your parent, instead of using a placeholder (the one you reference as `ModalContent`) that you have to hide. That way, whatever HTML you pass within that `<custom-dialog>` will be fed into your `Dialog`'s `<slot>` (designed beaviour of slot).

That way you also save the hassle of having to manually instantiate your Dialog component.

Then you can toggle your `<custom-dialog>` visibility (with `v-if` or `v-show`) or even manipulate its position in the DOM as you mention in your code; you can access its DOM node as `$el`: `this.$refs.ModalContent.$el` when `ModalContent` is a Vue instance.

You could also factorize the `showModal` method by delegating it to the `Dialog` component.

Code example:

```js
Vue.component('modal-dialog', {
  template: '#modal-dialog',
  data() {
    return {
      modalShown: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.modalShown = true;
    },
    hideModal() {
      this.modalShown = false;
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$refs.ModalContent.showModal();
    },
  },
});
```

```css
/*
https://sabe.io/tutorials/how-to-create-modal-popup-box
MIT License https://sabe.io/terms#Licensing
*/

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  width: 24rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.close-button {
  float: right;
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.close-button:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <modal-dialog ref="ModalContent">
    Hello!
  </modal-dialog>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <button v-on:click="showModal">Show modal</button>
</div>

<template id="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal" :class="{'show-modal': modalShown}" @click="hideModal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button" ref="closeButton" @click="hideModal">&times;</span>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Now if you *really* want to fiddle with `$slot`, @Sphinx's [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50243546/5665870) in the question comments is an acceptable approach. Note that the accepted answer there also favours the standard usage. It seems to me this is also what @Sphinx implies in their 2nd comment.